# What the meaning of the phrase 'I winter well' in this video?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

the passage:

> I'm a big guy, **I winter well**

[**link to the video**](https://youtu.be/uDYba0m6ztE?t=355)

Comment: (Without having watched the video) I think it means "I cope with the conditions of winter well"

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would imagine that the big guy means that "He [can hibernate just like a bear](https://beartrust.org/do-bears-hibernate) because he's a big guy (like a bear)."

Comment: To add to what Teacher KSHuang has said: the subject at that moment in the video is health, and so when he refers to his body, which is not fit or sleek, he could be alluding to the layer of fat a bear puts on during the autumn in preparation for its long hibernation without food. He says that he is speaking "euphemistically", in other words, he is saying that he is a fat fellow.

Comment: Usually, fat is supposed to keep you warmer, so saying that you're a big guy, and that you winter well, means that you have more fat, and so you keep warmer in winter. He's using a noun, winter, as a verb (to winter) for effect.